# Unable to execute import-hive.sh

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-atlas

I am getting below error while running import-hive.sh
Could you please help me out on this?

```
  hadoop@0.0.0.0:~/apache-atlas-2.1.0/hook/apache-atlas-hive-hook-2.1.0/hook-bin$ ./import-hive.sh
    Using Hive configuration directory [/home/hadoop/hive/conf]
    Log file for import is /home/hadoop/apache-atlas-2.1.0/hook/apache-atlas-hive-hook-2.1.0/logs/import-hive.log
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,449 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Looking for atlas-application.properties in classpath
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,452 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Loading atlas-application.properties from file:/home/hadoop/hive/conf/atlas-application.properties
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,505 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Using graphdb backend 'janus'
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,505 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Using storage backend 'hbase2'
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Using index backend 'solr'
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Atlas is running in MODE: PROD.
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Setting solr-wait-searcher property 'true'
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Setting index.search.map-name property 'false'
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Setting atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size = 150
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache = true
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.tx-cache-size = 15000
    2021-07-13T15:43:21,506 INFO [main] org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties - Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.tx-dirty-size = 120
    Enter username for atlas :- admin
    Enter password for atlas :-
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/client/ConnectionConfigurator
            at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.getClient(AtlasBaseClient.java:287)
            at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.initializeState(AtlasBaseClient.java:454)
            at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.initializeState(AtlasBaseClient.java:449)
            at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.<init>(AtlasBaseClient.java:132)
            at org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2.<init>(AtlasClientV2.java:94)
            at org.apache.atlas.hive.bridge.HiveMetaStoreBridge.main(HiveMetaStoreBridge.java:134)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.ConnectionConfigurator
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
            ... 6 more
    Failed to import Hive Meta Data!!!
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? import all tables from hive ? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: yes. I am trying to import hive metadata into atlas.